# scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d not working

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.ndimage

I am trying to use scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d for the first time, but it's not going well. Here's what I'm trying

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter1d

def test(x):
    return x.sum()

im_cube = np.zeros((100,100,100))
calc = generic_filter1d(im_cube, test, filter_size=5, axis=2)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: test() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I'm using scipy 1.4.1 What am I doing wrong?

For the function, I also tried np.mean but then I got this:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d.html), the callback accepts two arguments: a reference to the input line, and a reference to the output line. It does not return the output, but rather modifies the provided buffer in-place.

If you want to implement a rolling sum filter, you will need to do that somewhat manually. For example:

```
def test(x, out)
    out[:] = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, strides=x.strides * 2, shape=(5, x.size - 4)).sum(axis=0)
```

To make it a mean, add `/ 5` at the end.

The purpose of `genetic_filter1d` is to format the edges and run the outer loop. It does not actually implement the rolling filter for you. You are still required to implement the entire inner loop yourself.

Comment: Okay yeah that must be the problem. But I'm still confused about how to pass the correct arguments. Do you know?